# Java: System.setErr after first setErr does not write to file

Tags: java, io, stream

I have a server program using System.setErr() to use as logging. I am having a problem closing the last PrintStream and opening a new one to write to.

This is how it is initialized:

```
File file = new File("file" + "_.txt");
for (int i = 1; file.exists(); i++) {
    file = new File(String.format("file" + "_%d.txt", i));
}

System.setErr(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)), true));
```

This is how it is restarted:

```
System.err.flush();
System.err.close();
File file = new File("file" + "_.txt");
for (int i = 1; file.exists(); i++) {
    file = new File(String.format("file" + "_%d.txt", i));
}

System.setErr(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)), true));
```

The problem is that whatever is sent to the new PrintStream for System.err does not print. Only portions of it print, but the majority (in multiple threads) do not.

Would love some help,
Thanks!

Comment: So the *relevant* information, not shown in code is "**..in multiple threads..**"?

Comment: I can't seem to understand. System.err is static, shouldn't setting a new PrintStream cause all future calls to System.err to print to the new stream?

Comment: Hypothesis: the problem (of "only portions of [the output print]") does not occur in when threads are not involved. Test this; that will either allow elimination of threads or indicate that threading is involved.

Comment: Also, note that while that the `System.err` is static, it is *not volatile* and the entire flush/close/re-open is *non-atomic*. Without further code (that probably shows the involvement of threads), it is unlikely that the "problem" can be precisely explained.

Comment: @user2864740 Actually didn't think of that! That could mean that I would have to implement my own version of System.err that is volatile.

Thanks for the insight! I'll test this out tomorrow :)

Comment: I suspect it "may work" if using something like: `synchronized (..) { PrintStream oldErr = System.err; System.setError(OpenNewStream()); } Sleep_X_Milliseconds(); CloseOldStream(oldErr);`. There is *still a race condition* where System.err is not yet picked up by a new thread 'before' the close, but it should be 'minimal' due to a sleep: basically, the old stream should not be closed if there are *any* references to it. (Where there is a very small chance that 'newer' stuff is written to the 'older' file for a very brief window.)

Comment: To get around the race condition, consider implementing a `"RedirectableStream"` *that uses proper synchronization guards internally*. It could be (at start of program before threads, eg): `RedirecatableStream x = ..; System.setError(new PrintStream(x));` and later on `x.targetNewFile("xyz")`.

Comment: Alternatively, one could abuse the fact that `PrintStream` *synchronizes on itself*, so.. `synchronized (System.err) { PrintStream oldErr = System.err; System.setError(OpenNewStream()); CloseOldStream(oldErr); }` *might* be 100% thread-safe if the System.err re-assignment was only called from a single thread (if called from multiple threads, would require a secondary synchronization) - this takes 'advantage' of an implementation detail.